# Configure initiator on CentOS for two Targets

Tags: iscsi, initiator

I have an old Promise VTrak M500i SAN Server. It comes with 2 iSCSI ports. I have given each port an IP:

```
 port1 - 192.168.2.12  
 port2 - 192.168.2.13
```

I have two Logical Drives on this SAN and they are mapped as follows:

```
 Index  Initiator Name                LUN Mapping  
 0         iqn.2011-11:backup           (LD0,0)  
 1         iqn.2011-11:template         (LD1,1)
```

I want to create one Target on each port to separate the traffic. So, iqn.2011-11:backup will go through port1 and iqn.2011-11:template will go through port2 to the Initiator server(CentOS).

When I discovery on one IP from a CentOS server, it found both targets:

[root@centos ~]# iscsiadm -m discovery -t sendtargets -p 192.168.2.12

```
 192.168.2.12:3260,1 iscsi-1  
 192.168.2.13:3260,2 iscsi-1
```

[root@centos ~]# iscsiadm -m discovery -t sendtargets -p 192.168.2.13

```
 192.168.2.13:3260,2 iscsi-1  
 192.168.2.12:3260,1 iscsi-1
```

After restart the iSCSI service, it automatically create a new Target and map to the same Port:

```
 iqn.1994-05.com.redhat:8d3af9e5acb6    san     Port1 - 192.168.2.11  
 iqn.1994-05.com.redhat:8d3af9e5acb6    san     Port1 - 192.168.2.11
```

How do I set the Initiator iqn.2011-11:backup to port1 and iqn.2011-11:template to port2? Sorry for any confusion in my question if there is any. I am not familiar with the iSCSI. Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution is to have the two targets on separate subnets, and to assign each of the iSCSI portals an IP from each subnet, and also assign each NIC to a different subnet respectively. However, this way you're killing off any chance for multipathing, which is not the best idea. Instead, keep accessing both portals and targets using both NICs, the separation on the host side can be achieved by either subnetting (in this case leave both targets visible through both portals) or using the `Iface` parameter of the `iscsiadm` command

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I would prefer to use the first method. Currently, it seems both targets are viable through both portals. Do I need to do anything?

Comment: depends on whether your SAN allows zoning targets to specific portals